# Magento 2 - 'Add Subcategory' button not showing in catalog categories

Tags: magento2, category

I don't understand why the **Add Category** button isn't showing up in my store. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Index and cache are normal. Every other button including the upload button works normally.

Screenshot[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please switch your Default store View to **All Store Views**. after you can add a category.

Comment: It didn't work. Any other suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Please switch your `Default store View` to `All Store Views`. after you can add a category.

Please see below screenshot,

[image]

Comment: I have done that but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: On which Magento version you work? **@Daniel**

Comment: On magento 2.2.1.  I really don't know what next to do and I really need a fix fast.

Comment: Please add screenshot after the change to All Store Views.

Comment: Screenshot is the same.. Just with a difference in store view name... It is selected to all to view. Atleast I know that much.

Comment: I even tried to check console if there is any .js error or something related to third party extension but, nothing seem to show as the problem.

Comment: Any system message on the top of admin?

Comment: No... None. I just don't seem to understand what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Switch **Store View** to "All Store Views" option

Comment: Not Working. Switched and Cleared cache also

Answer (score 0):

Well, since this seem like a problem only I had, i just did a simple work-around of upgrading the system with fresh install of latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I am facing tried to resolve by debbuging in `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tree::_prepareLayout()`.
You will get `false` in first if codition some time. you will get more idea in this file.

May be it will help you to resolve your problem.